# Verify: A differentiable function has a continuous approximation function

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity, proof-writing

A function $s_a$ is defined as a *secant function* of $f$ at $a$ if $f(x) - f(a) = s_a(x)(x-a)$.  Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if there exists a secant function $s_a$ continuous at $a$, in which case $s_a(a) = f'(a)$.  Use this to prove the Chain Rule.

*Note: Proofs are available.  This question asks for verification and critique of* this *proof.*

**Proof:** For a fixed $f$ and $a$, each value at $a$ uniquely determines exactly one secant function $s_a$.  Thus, a secant function continuous at $a$ exists if and only if there exists a value at $a$ which makes the corresponding $s_a$ continuous at $a$.  This, in turn, is met if and only if $s_a(x)$ has a limit as $x \to a$.  But

$$\lim_{x \to a}s_a(x) = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} = f'(a).$$

Thus, if and only if $f'(a)$ exists, then a $s_a$ continuous at $a$ exists with $s_a(a) = f'(a)$.

**Chain Rule:** Given $f$ differentiable at $a$ and $g$ differentiable at $f(a)$, then $g \circ f$ is differentiable at $a$ with derivative $g'(f(a)) \cdot f'(a)$.

*Proof:* By the theorem above, we have
$$\begin{align*}f(x) - f(a) &= s_a(x)(x-a) \\
g(x) - g(f(a)) &= r_{fa}(x)(x - f(a))\end{align*}$$
with $s_a$ continuous at $a$ and $r_{fa}$ at ${f(a)}$. Consequently, $$q(x) := g'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x) = r_{fa}(f(x)) \cdot s_a(x)$$ is continuous at $x=a$.  Therefore

$$\begin{align*}q(x)(x-a) &= r_{fa}(f(x)) \cdot s_a(x)(x - a) \\
&= r_{fa}(f(x)) \cdot (f(x) - f(a))) \\
&= g(f(x)) - g({f(a)}) \\
&= (g \circ f)(x) - (g \circ f)(a)\\
\end{align*}$$
and $g \circ f$ is differentiable at $a$ with derivative $q(a)$, completing the proof.

**Questions:** Is the proof correct and rigorous? How could the writing be made more clear?

---

**Update:** I haven't received any responses.  Could someone comment if:

1. The proof is correct (and so no comment because no obvious errors)
2. The proof is incorrect, unclear, or otherwise jumbled (and so no comment because too jumbled to verify pr discuss)

Comment: I can't understand what you did in the line following "consequently".

Comment: I think you should replace $q(x) := g'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x) = r_{fa}(f(x)) \cdot s_a(x)$ with $q(x) := r_{fa}(f(x)) \cdot s_a(x)$. Rest of the proof seems fine. The strategy used is same as the one given in Spivak's *Calculus* with different notation.

Comment: However I find the direct proof using definition of derivative a bit simpler to handle as it avoids unnecessary functions like the secant function used in your proof. But that's just my personal opinion and not a problem with your approach.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Is the error in the line $q(x) := g'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x) = r_{fa}(f(x)) \cdot s_a(x)$ that while it is true that $q(a)$ agrees with $g'(f(a)) \cdot f'(a)$, it is _not_ true in general that $q(x)$ agrees with $g'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x)$? And the solution you recommend is simple: Cut the middle part of the equation out.  Then, we've shown that for all $a, q_a(a) = g'(f(a)) \cdot f'(a) = (g \circ f)'(a)$, so QED? (This point should probably be made explicit at the end of the proof.) Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: @SRobertJames Your proof has basically stood up to 145 views in the past almost 7 days. Good work!

Comment: @SRobertJames A clearer notation for $s_a$ could be $s_{f,a}$. Then you would have $s_{g, f(a)}$ and $s_{g\circ f, g(f(a))}$ consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proofs are correct and rigorous basically, as I have checked. Here are some comments.

##### On the proof for the equivalence of the differentiability of $f$ and the existence of a continuous "secant function"

It is clearer to prove the "if" direction and "only if" direction separately in general. (There are exceptions such as transformations of equalities, which only support the general rule.) Nevertherless, your proof shows the equivalence very clearly.

##### On the proof for $g\circ f$ is differentiable

The definition, "$q(x) := g'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x)$" is wrong. $q(x)= g'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x)$ is only true when $x=a$ in general. What you wanted to say is simply "$q(x):=r_{fa}(f(x)) \cdot s_a(x)$".  Taking $x=a$, we know $q(a)=r_{fa}(f(a)) \cdot s_a(a)=g'(f(a))\cdot f'(a)$.

---

The following part is not about your proofs.

##### On the definition of "secant function"

> A function $s_a$ is defined as a *secant function* of $f$ at $a$ if $f(x) - f(a) = s_a(x)(x-a)$.

There are multiple issues with this definition.

- A "secant function" has been universally defined as the reciprocal of the cosine function basically. It is confusing to assign a different meaning.
- The function maps an $x\not=a$ to the slope of the secant that cuts the graph of $f$ at point $(a, f(a))$ and $(x, f(x))$. I would call it "a slope function of $f$ relative to $a$" or "a slope function of $f$ about $a$".
- The domain and codomain of the function is not defined explicitly. This might be good for faster understanding so as to concentrate on the main content. However, it is not ideal for correctness and rigor.

  - $f$ should be defined on a neighborhood of $a$.
  - Also, $a$ should in the domain of $f$.
  - The domain of $s_a$ can be defined the same as that of $f$.
  - The codomain of $s_a$ can be the same as that of $f$, either real numbers or complex numbers.